# Error : CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Product'

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios5

I start to use core data with ios 5. I have my product model :

Product.m :

```
#import "Product.h"
@implementation Product
    @dynamic category_id;
    @dynamic label;
    @dynamic price;
@end
```

Product.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface Product : NSManagedObject 
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *category_id;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *label;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *price;
@end
```

I try to parse an xml with a custom class using NSXMLParserDelegate. My xml looks like :

```
<section id="2">
  <label>Animaux</label>
  <image>Images/Rayons/Bandeau/Animaux.png</image>
  <key>Images/Rayons/Bandeau/Animaux.png</key>
  <products>
     <Product id="21">
        <category_id>Chat</category_id>
        <label>Aliments pour chat</label>
        <price>2.00</price>
     </Product>
     <Product id="1286">
        <category_id>Chat</category_id>
        <label>Boite de paté</label>
        <price>0.00</price>
     </Product>
  </products>
</sections>
```

When i have a balise Product, I build my model like this :

```
item = [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init];
```

And when i have a property as category_id, i do :

```
[item setValue:currentNodeContent forKey:elementName];
```

And i got the error :

**CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Product'**

Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The docs for [NSManagedObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html) state that the dedicated intializer is:

```
initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:
```

which is why that is failing. Most of the examples I have seen suggest you should get a new object like this

```
[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyClass" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
```

So you could try something like:

```
[NSEntityDescription entityForName:className inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
```

Comment: You don't need the `NSClassFromString()`, since `entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` wants an `NSString` for the entity name.

Comment: Yes, i tried with this code but my application crash without specific error : [NSEntityDescription entityForName:className inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext] , how have i to declare the managedObjectContext ?

Comment: I solved my problem getting my managedObjectContext using AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];